# Load internet links from HTML string

Tags: iphone, html, ios, uiwebview

I am using the function (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL

```
[webView loadHTMLString:sourceCode baseURL:nil];
```

to load some source-code I wrote, with links to internet content. For instance :

```
<a href="http://www.google.fr/" title="Links to google">Google</a>
```

The string load well, but there is no way to access the google link then.
Do you know what I am doing wrong ? Is there anything to do with the baseURL ?

Answer (score 0):

your webpage must return a string that just contain http://www.google.com. If you need to use the link, you must modify the NSString that you receive to extract the right url!

Comment: and if I want to import an image in my sourceCode such as http://www.fredzone.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/google-docs-revision.jpg ? I can't just modify the string, and I prefer to avoid importing the image in the bundle.

Comment: @Nielsou the easiest way is to simply return the URL of the picture ;-) but Imran have the solution to extract the url from that page ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `dataDetectorType` for your webview like this:

```
webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

Hope this helps!